# Can a workflow be triggered from a post-build action of a freestyle project?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I have a Jenkins Workflow which I am able to run by clicking *Build*. But when I try to start it from the *Build other projects* post-build action of an (freestyle) project, I just get an error in the form

> my-flow is not buildable

and the downstream flow is not run when the upstream project is built.

Answer (score 3):

The post-build action *Build other projects* does not simply do what it sounds like: build those projects when the step is run. In fact running the step [does nothing at all](https://github.com/jglick/jenkins/blob/86bf6b7603c5c51c8ffc34fe1e78698fa9d03d3e/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/BuildTrigger.java#L181). Instead, it causes the named projects to be included in an edge of the dependency graph, and downstream projects according to the graph are then run according to separate logic. And currently the dependency graph API is defined in such a way that Workflow jobs cannot participate. Long story short, that mode does not work.

The Parameterized Trigger plugin offers other ways to start downstream jobs. The nonblocking trigger works much like the Jenkins core trigger: it affects the dependency graph. There is also a blocking trigger (which is a build step, not a post-build action), which just does what you probably expected: start the downstream build (much like the `build` step in Workflow). Currently this plugin does not support Workflow, though it would probably be easy to make it use more current APIs so that it would: [JENKINS-26050](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26050)

What *does* work is to configure the relationship in the reverse direction: in the Workflow job configuration, select *Build after other projects are built* and select your freestyle project. Now when the freestyle project finishes building, the Workflow job is triggered.

Comment: I filed [JENKINS-28113](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28113) to have the forward trigger in Jenkins core accept workflow jobs.

Comment: Note that as of version 2.28 of the Parameterized Trigger plugin, invoking downstream Workflow projects is supported (as evident by the status and comments of JENKINS-26050).